# Extending the separator line to maximium in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

By default the separator line is not long enough to reach both sides.

So I tried to extend it to the maximum:

```
[cell setSeparatorInset: UIEdgeInsetsMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, 0.5f)];
```

But that doesn't work. The length never changes. Am I missing something?

P.S I will need different settings for different rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `viewDidLoad:`

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

Comment: So this is a global option not possible for a single row ..?

Comment: for a single row, you could use a header cell I think ?

Comment: Make sense. Two sections with a small height solved the problem ;-P

Comment: @warl0ck Please validate the answer if it has fixed your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

In your storyboard file select the tableview, go to the attributes inspector, select custom separator insets and change the Left value to 0. Like this:

[image]